# Javascript regex to match items enclosed by a pair of characters?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want a regex to match everything between the  characters `(*` and `*)`. I also need `(*` and `*)` to be matched in the result as well.

For example;

Such a regex is applied to the code below;

```
(*
  * Something here
  * Many things can appear here
  * More things can appear here
  * Added another can appear here
*)

(*****************************************) Something here

Something here (*****************************************) 


(* Content can also exist here *) Something here

Something here (* Content can also exist here *) 


(Some content here ) (* Content can also exist here *) 

  * Something here
  * Many things can appear here
  * More things can appear here
  * Added another can appear here
```

The result only contains;

```
(*
  * Something here
  * Many things can appear here
  * More things can appear here
  * Added another can appear here
*)

(*****************************************) 

(*****************************************) 


(* Content can also exist here *) 

(* Content can also exist here *) 

(* Content can also exist here *)
```

I had something going on https://regexr.com/4nset

```
([\(\*].*(?:\*\)))
```

but it seems to not be working as expected.

Comment: Can you ever have nested parentheses in your input?

Comment: This doesn't look like a job for RegExp. Rather some sort of ast parser.

Comment: @BDawg no you can't

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming there are no nested or escaped brackets, you may use this regex in Javascript:

```
/\(\*[\s\S]*?\*\)/g
```

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regexr.com/4op3d)

**RegEx Details:**

- `\(\*`: Match starting `(*`
- `[\s\S]*?`: Match 0 or more of any characters including newlines (non-greedy)
- `\*\)`: Match closing `*)`

Answer (score 2):

`/\(\*.*?\*\)/gs`, where the `s` flag helps the dot symbol to match newline characters.

**NOTE**: This doesn't work cross-browser as of now. Other answers should be more suitable until it is properly supported.

```js
const str = `(*
  * Something here
  * Many things can appear here
  * More things can appear here
  * Added another can appear here
*)

(*****************************************) Something here

Something here (*****************************************) 


(* Content can also exist here *) Something here

Something here (* Content can also exist here *) 


(Some content here ) (* Content can also exist here *) 

  * Something here
  * Many things can appear here
  * More things can appear here
  * Added another can appear here`

const re = /\(\*.*?\*\)/gs

console.log(
  str.match(re)
)
```

Comment: sadly, the `s` flag is not widely supported yet. E.g. firefox doesn't yet.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
(\(\*[^\(]*(?:\*\)))/gmi
```

Here is a link to a Regex101 working demo: https://regex101.com/r/eB4a4U/2/